# Detect iPhone Browser

Tags: php, javascript, iphone, html, mobile-safari

is there a script to detect, if the visitor use iphone (whatever it's browser, may iphone Safari, iPhone for Opera or etc.)?

Then will shutdown some some of my JavaScript.

Thanks...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

searching on the net there are two common ways of achieving this.
My favorite though is in PHP its just so clean? wow. :D

**In PHP you can write**

```
<?php

function isIphone($user_agent=NULL) {
    if(!isset($user_agent)) {
        $user_agent = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] : '';
    }
    return (strpos($user_agent, 'iPhone') !== FALSE);
}

if(isIphone()) {
    header('Location: http://www.yourwebsite.com/phone');
    exit();
}

// ...THE REST OF YOUR CODE HERE

?>
```

**and in javascript you can write**

```
var agent = navigator.userAgent;
var isIphone = ((agent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1) || (agent.indexOf('iPod') != -1)) ;
if (isIphone) {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.yourwebsite.com/phone';
}
```

Hope that helps.

**PK**

Comment: Great... thanks you very much give the code in PHP Script. seems it's the best solution, since i want do different task for different browser which i want it to be processed from the server :D

Comment: i know exactly what you mean. I love php. When a user right click source you cant see any of the code used to program the site. Its very flexible as well. and its easy to use. All the code is processed on the server which is a bonus. Hope this helps.
if you need any more help... do let me know. Tweaking of this code can be done if any is needed to be done.

Comment: infact you can enhance this code to also check if it is an ipod. if you need help with that do let me know.
Also while you're here mark this post as answered thanks. so people know that this is the correct answer and they can then use this as a reference as youve tried it out. thank you

Comment: yes, i will mark this as correct answer as soon i test this in iPhone environment :D, now i still download the virtual software to test it's :)... Thank you very much :D

Comment: Hello i already test this with my Tester it's work, now i need for Ipad too. can you help me with the code?

Comment: Hi for ipad detection is very simple. you can either the word iPhone' in the php code with 'iPad' and that will work. Another way you can do it which i found out today is by using one line which will store a boolean value in a variable to say whether or not there is a device being detected based on the name you give, (iPhone, iPod, iPad):

$isiPad = (bool) strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPad');

Comment: Shouldn't that actually be `agent.indexOf('iPod')` in the JS version?

Comment: whoops, thanks for spotting the error. changes have been made

Answer (score 7):

The conventional wisdom is that iOS devices have a user agent for Safari and a user agent for the UIWebView. This assumption is incorrect as iOS apps can and do customize their user agent. The main offender here is Facebook.

Compare these user agent strings from iOS devices:

```
# iOS Safari
iPad: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B176 Safari/7534.48.3
iPhone: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3

# UIWebView
iPad: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/98176
iPhone: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/8B117

# Facebook UIWebView
iPad: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU iPhone OS 5_1_1 like Mac OS X; en_US) AppleWebKit (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile [FBAN/FBForIPhone;FBAV/4.1.1;FBBV/4110.0;FBDV/iPad2,1;FBMD/iPad;FBSN/iPhone OS;FBSV/5.1.1;FBSS/1; FBCR/;FBID/tablet;FBLC/en_US;FBSF/1.0]
iPhone: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 5_1_1 like Mac OS X; ru_RU) AppleWebKit (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile [FBAN/FBForIPhone;FBAV/4.1;FBBV/4100.0;FBDV/iPhone3,1;FBMD/iPhone;FBSN/iPhone OS;FBSV/5.1.1;FBSS/2; tablet;FBLC/en_US]
```

Note that on the iPad, the Facebook UIWebView's user agent string includes 'iPhone'.

**The old way to identify iPhone in JavaScript:**

```
IS_IPHONE = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) != null) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) != null);
```

If you were to go with this approach for detecting iPhone, you would end up with IS_IPHONE being true if a user comes from Facebook on an iPad. That could create some odd behavior!

**The correct way to identify iPhone in JavaScript:**

```
IS_IPAD = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
IS_IPHONE = (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) != null) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) != null);
if (IS_IPAD) {
  IS_IPHONE = false;
}
```

We declare IS_IPHONE to be false on iPads to cover for the bizarre Facebook UIWebView iPad user agent. This is one example of how user agent sniffing is unreliable. The more iOS apps that customize their user agent, the more issues user agent sniffing will have. If you can avoid user agent sniffing (hint: CSS Media Queries), DO IT.

Answer (score 3):

```
//Detect special conditions devices
$iPod    = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");
$iPhone  = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$iPad    = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad");
$Android = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
$webOS   = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"webOS");

//do something with this information
if( $iPod || $iPhone ){
    //browser reported as an iPhone/iPod touch -- do something here
}else if($iPad){
    //browser reported as an iPad -- do something here
}else if($Android){
    //browser reported as an Android device -- do something here
}else if($webOS){
    //browser reported as a webOS device -- do something here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
    //This redirects iPhone users to the iPhone-friendly site
    if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1) ||
    (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPod') != -1)) {
        document.location = "http://i.yoursite.com";
    }
```

This script checks for iPhone or iPod in the userAgent and then executes an action.  Give this a try.

Comment: Ok, let me know how it goes for you.  I've used it several times and seems to pick up find.  The next step is adding other strings and then adding actions for each of them depending on the functionality you want.

Answer (score 1):

Although I like the answers here, I think its better to use the following ...

http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/detect-and-redirect-iphone/

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone
RewriteRule .* http://iphone.example.com/ [R]
```

OR

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my-iPhone-site/
RewriteRule .* /my-iPhone-site/ [R]
```

This is a .htaccess alternative, which means leaves you more room to deal with php :) hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Late, indirect answer to this question, but I found it useful.

Instead of redirecting mobile users, consider using responsive CSS design to deliver desktop and mobile users the same content with two different styles.  This helps avoid splitting and duplicating code.  You can code responsive CSS from scratch, or use prepackaged frameworks like Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: I don't think responsive css is good for design dekstop and mobile at once, because what information we want to show in dekstop and mobile will be different. e.g we didn't what much information in mobile which make the design looks complicated. Responsive design i think is designed to make website is look goods in different display screen.

Comment: The OP wasn't asking because in order to redirect, but to avoid running a script.