# How to get a thumbnail from an embedded video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to embed a video into a webpage using lightbox. From a design perspective, how should I place the video on the page.

I mean the videos are lined up across the page as thumbnails.  Should I take a frame from the video and display that as an image that the user clicks? Or does the various video plugins take care of creating the thumbnail for you?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323053/dynamically-using-the-first-frame-as-poster-in-html5-video

Answer (score 0):

If you're using HTML5, the thumbnail of a video is defined using the 'poster' attribute in the video tag. Here's an example:

```
<video width="500" height="375" poster="myThumbnail.jpg" preload="none" controls="controls">
  <source src="http://hostname.com/myVideo.webm"/>
</video>
```

If you want to create this image automatically using a given frame of the video, you should check the link posted by F. Calderan