# Using a frame from the video as the preview poster in videoJS

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video, video.js

I'm trying to get videoJS to display a frame from the video as the poster image.

How can I achieve this?

The docs seem to show it is only possible to load in a static image...?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically using the first frame as poster in HTML5 video?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323053/dynamically-using-the-first-frame-as-poster-in-html5-video)

Answer (score -1):

You can try append time in seconds `#t={seconds}` to source URL:

```
<video playsinline src="testvideo.mp4#t=0.1"></video>
```

Comment: though the best way for me was poster - image first frame video host by backend service