# Video.js-Could not get thumbnail image of video automatically

Tags: php, html, html5-video, video.js

I am using **"video.js"** based  **HTML5** tag to display video on my browser.But It can not grab the first frame of the video and show as thumbnail of video before the start up.So can anyone suggest me how can i get image automatically **without use of "poster" tag** in the video tag and pass the thumbnail path in the argument.Is it necessary to generate thumbnail of the video to show it?

thanks in advance..and please provide you valuable suggestions

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, VideoJS does not automatically extract a poster image. However, [Dynamically using the first frame as poster in HTML5 video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323053/dynamically-using-the-first-frame-as-poster-in-html5-video) shows you, how this can easily be acieved using [Popcorn.js](http://popcornjs.org/).

Comment: yes..but my client has asked me to do with video.js so ...i have to find the option with this only as site consistency is in concern.So cant we fulfil by the use of some parameters of video.js?

Comment: As already stated above, as far as I know, this is not possible.