# Getting a video thumbnail / snapshot with popcorn.js on ios not working

Tags: ios, cordova, capture, popcornjs

I have tried this:
[Dynamically using the first frame as poster in HTML5 video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323053/dynamically-using-the-first-frame-as-poster-in-html5-video)

to get a thumbnail of a video in HTML5 using popcorn.js on IOS, but it didn't work. the `'canplayall'` event didn't fire untill I clicked `play` on the video.
and then, there was no poster attribute added to the video.
On google chrome (PC) it worked 100%.

Any advice?