# monitor and browser screen resolution web site design

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am going to to have to redesign my company site to fit it into different accessing computer screens and even into phones, the current page using mostly div tags (I hear they want to change all of the current html pages into php ). I hear of fluid design but what it offers isn't how to scale the page down to some particular sizes like use of number%, is it ?

I have no idea where to go from here. Any advice and instructions please

Comment: I think you're looking for _Responsive web design_, I would recommend you [this book](http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design/).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in CSS. Best thing for you to do is to do a search for fluid CSS layouts. Here are a few good ones:

http://www.projectseven.com/whims/cssp_3box/

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/category/C10/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

Well You can use css media-queries to make your layout responsive check : http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/5-useful-css-tricks-for-responsive-design

Also if you wish to use php to detect different browsers/platforms 
check : [Detect iPhone Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827466/detect-iphone-browser) &
http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/

Answer (score 0):

You can use "responsive" design or stick to standard screen resolution "1024" or whatever you have in your statistics